# horizontal scroll in jQuery mobile in iPhone

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, horizontal-scrolling

I am writing a simple program for iPhone using jQuery mobile, I have created a div with number of images but the scroller that is coming is vertical which I don't want. I want vertical space to be fixed and overflow of images horizontally. I know there a re scrolling plugin like iScroll but in my case I cant use them because those scrolling plugins uses `<li>` with fixed number of elements to be showed on that page but I want to keep this dynamic, if user rotates his device horizontally then more images can fit in the screen so I want that adjustment that if user keep his device vertical then horizontally there is less space so images should scroll horizontally but if he rotates device horizontally then he gets more space  horizontally and more images can fit in and leftover images will again scroll horizontally.

I fixed the height of div and tried overflow property to let images flow horizontally but I guess jQuery is preventing that behavior.

can you please put me on correct path.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could still use iScroll for horizontal scrolling, but you need to call `refresh` method whenever the content dimensions change. In your case, you could listen to the `orientationchange` event and perform in that case `refresh` of your iScroll object.

Check the section "Mastering the refresh() method" in [iScroll documentation](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4).

Hope it helps!

EDIT. You can start testing with a quick example like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="loadPage">

<div data-role="content">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" onclick="addText();">Add text</a>
     <div id="scroller" style="border: 1px solid green; white-space: nowrap; width: 300px;">
         <div id="text" style="border: 1px solid red; height: 20px; width: 0px;"></div>
     </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var iscrollPage = null;
    $('#loadPage').bind('pagebeforeshow', function () { 
        iscrollPage = new iScroll($('#scroller').get(0), { vScroll: false, hScroll: true });
    });

    function addText() {
        $('#text').append((new Date()).getTime()).css('width', '+=140');
        iscrollPage.refresh();
    }
</script>

</div>
```

Comment: you mean I can use iScroll without using '<li>' elements in it? but then how scroll bar will come?

Comment: I tried it but it is not working. A jsfiddle example would be a great help